# Merge Tags [react.js] & [reactjs]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The two tags [react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react.js) and [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) are referring to the exact same thing. There are not many questions tagged with the [react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react.js) tag, but people can still use it.

I suggest to merge between the two.